# data inconsistency, laravel ORM loose matching

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I've data inconsistency issue, some models in DB have dashes some don't, some models in API have dash some not...

its a mad house.

```
$car[ 'model_id' ] = CarModel::where( 'name', $car[ 'model_name' ] )->first( [ 'id' ] );
```

How would I deal with this? str_replace is not an option, I just need to ignore '-' in comparisons.

possible?

Comment: give en example of dashed model

Answer (score 1):

You say that `str_replace` is not an option but if you pair it with `REPLACE`, you can effectively ignore dashes in your comparison by removing them from both your needle and haystack

```
 CarModel::whereRaw("REPLACE(name,'-','') = ?",
    array(str_replace('-','',$car['model_name'])))->first();
```

Keep in mind that this will prevent the db from taking advantage of any indexes you have on the `name` column, which may result in slow queries.